# Android: How to store Objects as primitive type in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I know there is the RawRowMapper that can convert the strings into an object in sqlite, but how to store the object as a string? Is there a similar -mapper when storing the object?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, using persisterClass field in the DatabaseField could solve this problem. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733464/how-to-specify-object-custom-serialization-in-ormlite)